# A python or R library for 3D plot that can use heigth and color independently

Tags: python, 3d, r

I'm plotting the effect of the interaction of two variables in two different dependent variables and want to present them both on a single plot.

I had a level plot showing the colors for one variable and lines for the second one, but I'd like the effect of the most important variable to be self evident while at the same time showing the second variable.

So I'd like to do a 3D surface plot with the height of the first variable and the color of the second variable. So far I haven't found a library that can handle this use case, most use the same variable for color and height without option to handle them separately.

An example of the required use case is shown in the picture:

[image: A 3D surface where color does not correspond with height]

Which python or R library can handle that use case?

Answer (score 0):

I was just introduced to plotyly, from my brief introduction it should handle your use case well.

https://plot.ly/python/
[Intuitive plotting for Python!][1]

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @karel Could you provide an example?

Comment: @xihh R library Installation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324093/error-in-grid-call/53368021#53368021 + Code example: [3D Plots with ggplot2 and Plotly](https://www.r-bloggers.com/3d-plots-with-ggplot2-and-plotly/) by Matt Sundquist, Plotly, co-founder

Comment: @karel All presented examples handle color as reinforcement for height and for showing the scale. Not the required use case.